# Spanning body text across multiple fixed height columns

Tags: jquery, css, multiple-columns

I have certain posts on my site that are formatted like a magazine using CSS3 multi-columns, such as [this post](http://riggl.es/post/16847560083/the-real-cost-of-digital). I would like to include IE users with the jQuery Columnizer plugin, but this still doesn't solve my biggest problem. As you can see in my post link, the article text is long and requires scrolling back up to the top of the next column to continue reading. I'd like to create a series of 3-column divs, say 600px high (could also be set by word-count instead of height), with the body text spanning across them. Some posts will need one such div, some will need a few, so the solution needs to accommodate different post lengths. I have searched, but have not found anything that covers my particular situation. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

Comment: It's a fairly complex pagination issue. You'd have to write it yourself.

Comment: Doesn't have to be 600px exactly. Perhaps inserting an all-column-spanning `<hr>` after x numbers of words?